# Invalid Redeclaration of "textViewDidChange" Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textbox

I have three different text box in which I need to use 3 different "textViewDidChange" methods. Combining them in one function is not working for me I they are three different actions that may effect each other. So I am trying to make three different functions as below. But I am getting the "invalid redeclaration" error. How can I figure it out?

```
func textViewDidChange(messageTxt1: UITextView) {

    var len = count(messageTxt.text.utf16)

    var diff = 90 - len

    if diff < 0 {

        charsLbl.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {

        charsLbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    charsLbl.text = "\(diff) chars left"

}


func textViewDidChange (messageTxt2: UITextView) {

    refreshResults()

    var len2 = count(messageTxt2.text.utf16)

    if len2 > 3 {

        println("search")

    }

    else

    {

        resultsTable.hidden = true

    }

    var diff2 = 30 - len2

    if diff2 < 0 {

        charsLbl2.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {

        charsLbl2.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    charsLbl2.text = "\(diff2) chars left"


}


func textViewDidChange (messageTxt3: UITextView) {


    var len3 = count(messageTxt3.text.utf16)

    var diff3 = 30 - len3

    if diff3 < 0 {

        charsLbl3.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {

        charsLbl3.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    charsLbl3.text = "\(diff3) chars left"


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you are creating three methods with same name `textViewDidChange`.
2. In your case use `tag` property and define only one method for all.

**Example**

```
let textView1 = UITextView()
textView1.tag = 1

let textView2 = UITextView()
textView2.tag = 2

let textView3 = UITextView()
textView3.tag = 3

In method just add condition for that.

func textViewDidChange (messageTxt: UITextView) {

if messageTxt.tag == 1
{
     // Your code for textview 1
}
else if messageTxt.tag == 2
{
      // Your code for textview 2
}
else if messageTxt.tag == 3
{
    // Your code for textview 3
}}
```

Comment: Why use tag when you can compare objects directly ? `messageTxt === textView1` does what you'd expect.

Comment: @Fantattitude you have to maintain reference for this.

Comment: Makes more sense to me to keep references, it's less error prone, than just use tag with "magic" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not possible because each `textViewDidChange:` method is taking the same types as parameter (the name of the variable inside the function scope doesn't play a role here).

One way to sort it out having several functions would be to have one `textViewDidChange:` method and use it as a way to call other functions like this :

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    switch textView {
    case textView1:
        textViewDidChange1()
        break
    case textView2:
        textViewDidChange2()
        break
    case textView3:
        textViewDidChange3()
        break
    default:
        print("Shouldn't happen")
        break
    }
}

func textViewDidChange1() {
    // Do something
}

func textViewDidChange2() {
    // Do something
}

func textViewDidChange3() {
    // Do something
}
```

textView1, textView2 and textView3 being Outlets to your UITextViews.
This looks a bit overkill to me but it works.

Comment: Thank you Fantattitude! That solved my problem. Great solution.